# Optimizing code in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angular directive init function i am declaring constant and utilizing the constant in html. I have multiple directives utilizing the same constant i want to keep the constants a reusable one.
In the below example i am using scope.sName and scope.sType in both test and test1 directive how can i have IT IN A COMMON PLACE AND REUSE IT.

```
app.directive('test', function() {
return {
  restrict:'A',
  scope: { someVal: '='}
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.sType = InvertoryConstant.serviceType;
    scope.sName = InvertoryConstant.serviceName;
}
}});

app.directive('test1', function() {
return {
  restrict:'A',
  scope: { someVal: '='}
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.sType = InvertoryConstant.serviceType;
    scope.sName = InvertoryConstant.serviceName;
}
}});
```

Comment: Put common code into a service and inject service into your directive.

Comment: is `InvertoryConstant` an object?, as it is a constant, its value wont change anywhere right?

Comment: and where do you have that constant now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$provider.constant` method in AngularJS for creating DRY constants:

```
angular.module('projectApp', [])
  .constant('EXAMPLE_CONSTANT','exampleConstant')
```

You can inject `EXAMPLE_CONSTANT` into any of your modules, as a dependency